# Bizzare PHP behaviour calculating time differences, only on 6th and 7th September, 2013

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the difference in days between two dates. I'm getting bizzare behaviour - I've narrowed it down to 6th and 7th October, 2013, as you can see below. Whenever the date range spans those dates, the calculation is a day out.

```
// WRONG! current year - 2013
$datediff = strtotime('2013-10-07') - strtotime('2013-10-06');
$startToEndDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
print_r($startToEndDays); // Outputs 0 - should output 1

// RIGHT! next year - 2014
$datediff = strtotime('2014-10-07') - strtotime('2014-10-06');
$startToEndDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
print_r($startToEndDays); // Outputs 1 - correct
```

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: At a very rough guess, daylight savings switchover?

Comment: ha yeah I just figured that.

Comment: The 10th month in the year is actually October :)  That being said, if you want to due date interval calculations, I would highly recommend using the DateTime and DateInterval classes rather than taking your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haha OK, it turns out 6th/7th October 2013 is when daylight savings starts in Sydney, Australia. So, the number of hours between those dates is calculated (correctly) as 23. But, 23 hrs is not quite a day.

If you're using PHP 5.3+, then this is how you should calculate the difference between dates in days, to save yourself any daylight savings headaches:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2013-10-07');
$endDate = new DateTime('2013-10-06');
$interval = $startDate->diff($endDate);
$days = $interval->days;
```